# É possível tornar uma Entidade relacionada possível de ser exibida com Odata Expand (WebApi)?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api

Olá,
Tenho uma dúvida em relação a seguinte situação:
Possuo uma Entidade que defini na minha model como TarefaFreq

```
public partial class TarefaFreq
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Criei alguns dados em uma lista estática:

```
public class TarefaFreqData
{
    public static IEnumerable<TarefaFreq> GetLista()
    {
        var list = new List<TarefaFreq>();
        list.Add(new TarefaFreq() { ID = 1, Name = "Teste 1" });
        list.Add(new TarefaFreq() { ID = 2, Name = "Teste 2" });            
        return list;
    }        
}
```

E possuo também a model Tarefa (Essa aqui está no banco de dados):

```
    public partial class Tarefa
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int FreqID { get; set; } 
        public virtual TarefaFreq Freq { get; set; }
    }
```

Nas configurações de minha webAPI com Entity-Framework se eu tento definir a minha propriedade:
`builder.EntityType<Tarefa>().Property(f => f.Freq);`
Obtenho o seguinte erro:
`The type TarefaFreq must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it ...`

Meu objetivo é que quando eu informar na URL:
`http://localhost:58170/odata/Tarefas(12)/?$expand=Freq`
Eu consiga obter os dados na resposta.

Lembrando que a Entidade TarefaFreq não estará no meu banco de dados, ela apenas foi criada para servir dados para uma chave estrangeira que está em meu banco de dados que é a propriedade de `Tarefa` -> `FreqID`, por isso a lista estática que criei. Nesse caso, como estou desenvolvendo no cliente preciso usar o `$expand` do ASP.NET Web API 2 OData.

Comment: Já tentou transformar em `struct`? Não conheço bem esses requisitos da ferramenta, mas isso deve resolver. Só não digo que é a solução correta. Será que o certo aí não é só usar o `ID` do objeto? Até está parecendo. Inclusive parece ser algo redundante no código.

Comment: @Maniero Bom, como está até então, está funcionando quando preciso criar a relação entre a chave estrangeira e o dados da minha lista. A solução do `$expand` para a entidade que `TarefaFreq` é que quando listo os detalhes essa informação não consegue vir mapeada no campo.